# Configuring jQuery's color animation effect

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Is there an effective way to use jQuery's standard color animation effect to create a collapsible section that, by default, only displays the h3 tag, but will then expand and collapse the "effect" div using the tool's standard functionality?

Here's the sample code from the jQuery site, which I'd like to use in this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Effects - Animate demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
.toggler { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
#button { padding: .5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
#effect { width: 240px; height: 170px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; background: #fff; }
#effect h3 { margin: 0; padding: 0.4em; text-align: center; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  var state = true;
 $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ( state ) {
    $( "#effect" ).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
      color: "#fff",
      width: 500
    }, 1000 );
  } else {
    $( "#effect" ).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      color: "#000",
      width: 240
      }, 1000 );
    }
    state = !state;
  });
   } );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="toggler">
 <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Animate</h3>
  <p>
  Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>

   <button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Toggle Effect</button>


   </body>
   </html>
```

Ideally, I would like to see this effect used such that only the h3 tag with the word "Animate" will display until someone clicks the button to toggle the effect. Thanks for your time and insights!

Regards,

Wyattburp86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.hide();` on your Text Element on document ready or whenever you wish will do the Trick. Then in the Button Click Event add `.show();` to the Text Element.

Working example:- https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/6/

More Info (W3s): https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: Thanks for the info and the example!